# ML-inequality for real integrals

Tags: real-analysis, integration

For a homework assignment from my analysis class, I was asked to show the following:

Let $f\colon [a,b] \to \mathbb{R} $ be Riemann integrable and $|f(x)| \le M$. Define $F(x) = \int_{a}^{x}f(t)dt$. Show that $|F(y) - F(x)| \le M|y-x|$.

To do this, I used the ML-inequality from complex variables:

If $|f(z)| \le M$ for all $z \in \text{Dom}(f)$ then $\left \lvert \int_C fdz \right\rvert \le ML$ where $L$ is the length of the curve $C$.

I want to know if this is appropriate. That is, does there exist an analogue of the ML-inequality for real numbers (integrals)? If so, what is it and is it similar enough to the above statement that I can use it without much modification?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ML inequality is (essentially) a *real* inequality. It holds for all (sufficiently regular, e.g. piecewise differentiable) curves and [again, sufficiently regular so that the integral is defined] functions [or vector fields] in any $\mathbb{R}^n$, $\mathbb{C}^n$ or more generally, Riemannian manifold. Its proof uses a) the inequality for real intervals [which is the thing you want to prove], and b) the representation of the length of the curve as $\int_a^b \lvert \gamma'(t)\rvert\,dt$. So appealing to the ML inequality is in serious danger of being circular.

But the monotonicity of the integral immediately gives you the conclusion, you have

$$F(y) - F(x) = \int_x^y f(t)\,dt,$$

and for $y \geqslant x$, you can estimate that by

$$\int_x^y (-M)\,dt \leqslant \int_x^y f(t)\,dt = F(y) - F(x) \leqslant \int_x^y M\,dt$$

due to the monotonicity of the integral. (For $y < x$, exchange $M$ and $-M$.)