# Prove that $\int _0^4\:f_n(x)\,dx < 4^{n+1}$ where $f_n(x)= \left(4x-x^2\right)^n$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis

$ f_n(x) = \left(4x-x^2\right)^n$

I'm trying to prove that $\int _0^4\:f_n(x)\,dx < 4^{n+1}$

When I'm doing a general integral to $n > 1$, I'm getting an expression that equals to zero when $X = 4$ or $X = 0$.

This is the expression:

$$\frac{\left(4x-x^2\right)^{n+1}}{(4-2X)(n+1)} $$

What am I missing? Because it doesn't make sense that every integral with $n > 1$ is equal to zero

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint**:

$4x-x^2$ is a quadratic polynomial , with a negative leading coefficient. Furthermore, it vanishes for $x=0$ and $x=4$. Can you find it (absolute) maximum?

Once you've found this maximum, you can use  the *mean value inequality for integrals*.

Comment: Of course, you can estimate this by the maximum! very nice approach. I like this argument. This is probably how the question was meant to be done ^^

Answer (score 4):

You cannot just blindly apply the reverse power rule. Remember the chain rule? You have a function within another function.

Consider the case when n=2

$ \int_0^4 (4x + x^2)^2 dx = \int_0^4 16x^2 + 8x^3 + x^4 dx$

Comment: Would it be better for him to use the binomial expansion, you think?

Comment: That would be an excellent approach. I was also thinking that you could attempt to find a pattern and then use induction to prove it.

Answer (score 2):

Below is a suggestion for a very tedious route, but I wanted to post it anyway. This is probably not how the question is meant to be done.

Observe how by the binomial theorem we have that:
$$I=\int _{x=0}^4\:f_n(x)\,dx =\int _{x=0}^4\: (4x-x^2 )^n\,dx  =\int _{x=0}^4\: \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} (4x)^{k} \cdot (-x^2)^{n-k}\,dx$$
We make this look a bit prettier: 
$$I=\int _{x=0}^4\: \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} 4^{k} \cdot (-1)^{n-k}x^{2n-k}\,dx$$

We may switch the order of integration and summation since this concerns polynomials (what I mean is that they are of finite order), we compute:
$$I=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} \frac{1}{2n-k+1} 4^{k} \cdot (-1)^{n-k}4^{2n-k+1}-0$$
We collect some terms:
$$I=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} \frac{1}{2n-k+1} 4^{2n+1} \cdot (-1)^{n-k}$$
Using combinatorial formulae and some help from Wolfram Alpha, this can be exactly computed to be:
$$ I =\frac{\sqrt {\pi} \cdot  n! \cdot 2^{2n+1}}{(n+\frac{1}{2})!}=\frac{\sqrt \pi \cdot n!}{(n+\frac{1}{2})!} \cdot  4^{n + \frac{1}{2}}$$
We then need to prove by induction that $\frac{\sqrt \pi \cdot n!}{(n+\frac{1}{2})!} > \sqrt{4}$ for positive $n$.

Yes. This is a lot of hard work. You could also just take the approach that was posted by Bernard and observe that $4x-x^2$ has a global maximum on the interval $[0,4]$ (the begin and endpoint are zeros of this polynomial), this maximum by symmetry occurs at $x=2$. The function has maximum value $8-4=4$. Observe then by the estimation lemma that $M =\max_{x \in [0,4]}((4x-x^2)^n)=4^n$, and  the length of our path is $4$. We get:
$$ \int _{x=0}^4 f_n dx \leq M L = 4^n \cdot 4 = 4^{n+1} $$

Also see: [ML-inequality for real integrals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1036818/ml-inequality-for-real-integrals)

Or alternatively, if you don't like applying this theorem, we see that the $f_n$ is continuous as it is a polynomial, it is bounded on $[0,4]$ , thus by the mean value theorem for integrals there must exist a $\xi \in [0,4]$ such that:
$$ (4-0) \cdot f_n(\xi) =\int _{x=0}^4\:f_n(x)\,dx$$
$$ \int _{x=0}^4\:f_n(x)\,dx = 4 f_n(\xi) $$
However, observe that $f_n(\xi) \leq 4^n$ for all $n \in \mathbb N$ thus:
$$ \int _{x=0}^4\:f_n(x)\,dx \leq  4 \cdot  4^n = 4^{n+1} $$

Answer (score 2):

If you let $I_n = \int_0^4 (4x-x^2)^ndx$ for every positive integer $n$, you can even find a recurrence relation for this sequence using integration by parts:

$$I_n = \int_0^4 (4x-x^2)^n dx = \int_0^4 (4x-x^2)^n \cdot (x-2)'dx = \cdots = -2nI_n + 8n I_{n-1}.$$

Using this you can easily solve your question using induction.

Comment: Or rewrite this as:
$$ I_{n+1}= \frac{8n}{1+2n} I_n $$
And then observe that in general the solution for $$ I_{n+1} = c_n \cdot I_{n} $$  is given by:
$$ I_ n= I_{n_0} \cdot  \prod_ {i=n_0} ^{n-1} c_i$$
Where $n_0$ denotes the starting index, that is, the first term.

Comment: Observe how $I_{n_0}=I_0 = 4$, we may then write that:
$$ I _n = 4 \cdot \prod_{i=0} ^{n-1} \frac{8n}{2n+1} <4 \cdot \prod_{i=0} ^{n-1} \frac{8n}{2n}= 4 \cdot \prod_{i=0} ^{n-1} 4 = 4^{n+1} $$

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nice solution without using the binomial expansion.

$$\int_0^4 (4x -x^2)^ndx < 4^{n+1}$$

If we let n=0, the integral resolves to 0 which is less than 4. So our base case is covered.

Now assume there exists a $k$ such that

$$\int_0^4 (4x -x^2)^kdx < 4^{k+1}$$

Holds.

Now we need to prove this inequality holds for the $k+1$.

$$\int_0^4 (4x -x^2)^{k+1}dx = \int_0^4 (4x -x^2)^k (4x - x^2)dx $$

If we apply integration by parts and let $u= 4x -x^2$ and $dv = (4x - x^2)^k$ we get

$$(4x - x^2) \int (4x -x^2)^kdx - (4 - 2x)\int(4x -x^2)^kdx $$

We let our bounds go from 0 to 4 and we get the following

$$0 \int_0^4 (4x -x^2)^kdx + 4 \int_0^4 (4x -x^2)^k$$

We know that $\int_0^4 (4x -x^2)^kdx < 4^{k+1}$ therefore we can conclude

$$4\int_0^4 (4x -x^2)^kdx < 4^{k+2}$$